# Add new column to existing dataframe from substring of existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks similar to this:

```
|email|first_name|last_name|id|group_email|
|-|-|-|-|-|
|drew@mail.com|drew|barry|05|san-red-gate-rate@mail.com|
|nate@mail.com|nate|lewis|03|san-blue-gate-factor@mail.com|
|chris@mail.com|chris|ryan|04|san-red-wheels-drive@mail.com|
```

I parse out the group_code, the sub string after the 3rd hyphen. I now want to add this sub tring back into the dataframe for each entry. So the df will look like so:

```
|email|first_name|last_name|id|group_email|group_code|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|drew@mail.com|drew|barry|05|san-red-gate-rate@mail.com|rate|
|nate@mail.com|nate|lewis|03|san-blue-gate-factor@mail.com|factor|
|chris@mail.com|chris|ryan|04|san-red-wheels-drive@mail.com|drive|
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try

```py
df['group_code'] = (df['group_email'].str.extract('(-[^@]*){3}')[0]
                    .str.lstrip('-'))
```

```
print(df)

            email first_name last_name  id                    group_email group_code
0   drew@mail.com       drew     barry   5     san-red-gate-rate@mail.com       rate
1   nate@mail.com       nate     lewis   3  san-blue-gate-factor@mail.com     factor
2  chris@mail.com      chris      ryan   4  san-red-wheels-drive@mail.com      drive
```